# jquery mobile collapsible animation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I am currently struggling with a collapsible set in Jquery Mobile. I want it animated when opening/closing as well as to slide up to the top of the screen when opened. It was working earlier in the project, but somehow stopped working down the line..

I have tried everything to find the problem without luck; The problem still persists without my CSS-sheets, and is still there without the added JS-coding. I have also tried different versions of jQuery and Jquery Mobile (and in different combinations) - still nothing.

I made a jsfiddle with all the relevant coding: https://jsfiddle.net/usa8bjh1/

This is the code I am using:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
$("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible({
    expand: function(event, ui){
        $(this).children().next().slideDown(500);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 0
        }, 800);
    },
    collapse: function(event, ui){
        $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
    }
});
});
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Use jQM 1.45 and `pagecontainershow` event with some delay `setTimeout` for the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your input - not quite sure how to implement the setTimeout, could you help me out with a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usa8bjh1/2/) with a working solution, binding the collapsible events this way:

```
$(document).on("collapsibleexpand", "[data-role=collapsible]", function () {
    $(this).children().next().slideDown(500);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 0
    }, 800);
});

$(document).on("collapsiblecollapse", "[data-role=collapsible]", function () {
    $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! However, I still can't get the opening and closing of the collapsibles to animate.. Any idea why?